# How can I get the car refinanced under my name if my girlfriend signed for the loan?

Tags: refinance, auto-loan

I was trying to get a car financed under my name and it turned out my girlfriend had much better credit than i did. She had a score of 826 and mine was like 560. So she signed on the loan solely under her name instead of mine, which saved us like $100 a month. I was wondering how I can refinance under my name with her as a cosigner later on or get the title under my name? I just want to find out how I can be safe if anything ever happens between us since I am making all the payments.

Comment: She wants to do this as well, just in case you turn up a flake and don't make payments.

Comment: two things. you can add a person to your title without needing to change the loan terms/conditions. Secondly, if you do get a loan for the car, you are still going to be in the original situation you were in (high interest rate because your credit sucks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to "buy" the car and get your own loan (like @ChrisInEdmonton answered).

That being said, my credit union let me add my spouse to a title while I still had a loan for a title filing fee.   You may ask the bank that holds the title if they have a provision for adding someone to the title without changing the loan.   Total cost to me was an afternoon at the bank and something like $20 or $40 (it's been a while).

Comment: +1, this may well be the easiest solution. The car would then be joint-owned, but that may be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

You should have her sell it to you for the amount of the outstanding loan. You take out a loan in your name for the amount (or at least, the amount you have to come up with). You then transfer the title from her to you, just as you would if you were buying the car from someone else.

While the title is in her name, she has ownership. This isn't a technicality, this is the explicit legal situation you two have agreed to.

Comment: can i apply for the new loan with her as a cosigner?

Comment: I'm not sure. If she cosigns, it's likely that she will have to be on the title for the car, which means you do not own it, or at least don't own it outright.

Comment: im just trying to find a way to get myself on it, with or without her

Comment: This would be a very expensive move if private party car sales are subject to sales tax in your state.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be to add your name to the title through the bank or have her sell it to you for the amount she owes then you get a loan for that amount like they said before. If you guys split up at this point she'll legally get to keep the car you've been paying for. You could apply for a new loan and have her cosign but it'll make your monthly payments higher. Have her sell you the car for the amount owed them you get a loan for that amount. Since you are together and you've been paying for it you won't lose any money and your monthly payments won't be expensive if you don't owe that much on the car. Pretty much having her sell it to you would be the smartest idea cause keeping Her name on the title will allow Her to legally drive away in your car if you split and you don't want that lol